# Assign array to another array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Lets say i have this  [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$first = ['hi', 'by', 'nice']
```

I am going to assign another array to this array items.In fact doing a `foreach` loop and due to situation assign a new array to desired array item.
Now i want turn it to this:

```
$second = ['hi', 'by' => ['really' => 'yes'], 'nice']
```

How can i do it programmatically?

Comment: are you wanting to add array2 values to array1 or add an array2 inside of an array1?

Comment: You need more detail.  Will you know the value `bye` ahead of time?  Will you know it's index `1` you want to change, etc...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$first = ['hi', 'by', 'nice'];

foreach( $first as $key => $value )
{
    $second[] = $value;
    if( $value == 'by' )
    {
        $second[ $value ][] = array( 'really' => 'yes' );
    }
}
var_dump( $second );
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "hi"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "by"
  ["by"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["really"]=>
      string(3) "yes"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  string(4) "nice"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$second = $first;
$tofind = 'by';
$key = array_search($tofind, $second);
unset($second[$key]);
$second[$tofind] = array( 'really' => 'yes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very important, if index `by` is known than you can use this index for checking and store values into a new array otherwise this will failed.

Here is basic example:

```
<?php
$first = ['hi', 'by', 'nice'];
$newArr = array();
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
    if($value == 'by'){
        $newArr[$value] = array('really'=>'yes');
    }
    else{
        $newArr[] = $value;
    }  
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi
    [by] => Array
        (
            [really] => yes
        )

    [1] => nice
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, actually there are many way exists to do this. This is mine,

```
<?php
$first = ['hi', 'by', 'nice'];
foreach($first as $k=>$v){
    if($v !='by'){
        $second[] = $v;
    }else{
        $second[$v] = ['really'=>'yes'];
    }
}
print_r($second);
?>
```